# How can we write to a printer in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, printing

We are porting our application over to GAE and one of the options it has is to render to a printer? Is this possible in GAE (being in the cloud it may not have the concept of printers). If so, how is that done? (Google search does not appear to show anything.)

thanks - dave

Comment: Is this an application users visit with a Web browser?

Comment: @chrylis - maybe. We have a reporting engine so it's there to do whatever the program calling it wants.

Comment: How does the current application render to a printer?, is it a desktop thick client that sends output directly to a connected printer?

Comment: @omerio it's presently used this way on servers that have a printer connected on the network.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.co.uk/cloudprint/learn/) in the office before where you can configure your printers and share them using Google Cloud Print. Here are a list of [Cloud Ready Printers](http://www.google.co.uk/cloudprint/learn/printers.html). There also seems to be an API for Cloud Print which I believe you can explore calling from your GAE servers using the [URL Fetch service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/), authentication is managed using OAuth2 for which you can use the [OAuth2 client libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2).

I think the first step is to check if you need to keep your existing printers and if they can be added to Google Cloud print, if this is possible then you can explore using the Cloud Print APIs from your GAE App, see the following links in the docs:

1. https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces
2. https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide

If your printers do not support cloud print unfortunately you might have to develop and expose your own API that accepts jobs and sends them over to network printers